# Advice required related to creation of Mobile site

Tags: zend-framework, mobile

A new client of mine has asked for us top recreate their small recruitment website. The main site is going to be done using Zend Framework 1.11 and mySql.

It is medium/small website for a team of two consultant recruiters which lists available positions with various companies and allows candidates to upload CVs and search for positions as well as displaying general information about the consultants.

They have asked that we also create a site capable of displaying on mobile devices (iPhone and Android) using a sub domain of their main site.

My question was this: Is it possible to point the mobi.myclientswebsitedomain.com to the www.myclientswebsitedomain.com site and simply change the layout used based on the detected device?

What is the best way to achieve this with the least effort?

Many thanks for any advice
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point your *mobi.* subdomain to the same webfolder as your *www.* domain. In your ActionController write conditional statment which will load different css files depending on the current subdomain.